# MessageBus and Replay

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

I tried to register to the MessageBus an observable that replay the last value produced when a new subscription occurs

```
var currentViewObs = currentViewGallery.ObservableForProperty(g => g.SelectedIndex)
                .Value().Select(CurrentViewObsSelector).Replay(1);

currentViewObs.Connect();

MessageBus.Current.RegisterMessageSource(currentViewObs, MessageBusContracts.CurrentView);
```

This doesn't work because the observable is wrapped in a ScheduledSubject which swallows the replay. Is there another way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you probably want to use your own MessageBus - implement `IMessageBus` (possibly by just copy-pasting code from [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/MessageBus.cs) and editing it), then assign it to `MessageBus.Current`